# how to show selected value of select box?

Tags: jquery, twig

i make a select box,i want to do when {{items.invoiceitemsid}}=2 second value make selected and then if {{items.invoiceitemsid}}=3 third value selected and show here is my code:

```
{% for items in itemdata %}
 {{items.invoiceitemsid}}
 if(({{items.invoiceitemsid}})==2){
 $('.items').find('option').remove().end();
        $('.items').append("<option value='1'>{{item1}}</option>").val('1');
        $('.items').append("<option value='2'>{{item2}}</option>").val('2');
        $('.items').append("<option value='3'>{{item3}}</option>").val('3');
 }
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try `{% for items in itemdata %}
 {{items.invoiceitemsid}}
 var $items = $('.items').find('option').remove().end();
 $items.append("<option value='1'>{{item1}}</option>").val('1');
 $items.append("<option value='2'>{{item2}}</option>").val('2');
 $items.append("<option value='3'>{{item3}}</option>").val('3');
 $items.val({{items.invoiceitemsid}})
{% endfor %}`

Comment: but it always show 2nd index not show first or second value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try :

```
{% for items in itemdata %}
    {{items.invoiceitemsid}}
    {{ set tofind = 2 }}
    if(({{items.invoiceitemsid}})== tofind ){
        $('.items').find('option').remove().end();
        $('.items').append("<option value='1' {% if tofind == 1 %}selected{% endif%}>{{item1}}</option>").val('1');
        $('.items').append("<option value='2' {% if tofind == 2 %}selected{% endif%}>{{item2}}</option>").val('2');
        $('.items').append("<option value='3' {% if tofind == 3 %}selected{% endif%}>{{item3}}</option>").val('3');
 }
 {% endfor %}
```